# how to view the dependency tree using buildr

Tags: build-process, buildr

Is there a way to view the dependency tree using buildr?

Something similar to what maven provides using the command:  "mvn dependency:tree".

Answer (score 1):

There is no task built in but depending on what you specifically need to do it is relatively easy to whip up some code to do it. We often write a little bit of code that looks like the following to list all transitive dependencies of a specific dependency.

```
task 'showdeps' do
  raise 'Need to define ENV property DEP' unless ENV['DEP']
  Buildr.transitive(ENV['DEP']).each do |a|
    puts a.to_spec
  end
end
```

And then run this via

```
buildr showdeps DEP=edu.ucar:tds:jar:classes:4.3.20
```

Not eactly what you asked for but hope this helps.